# chrome.tabCapture.capture returns null stream

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm having problems with this piece of code, it seems the stream passed to the callback of chroma.tabCapture.capture is null

```
var receiver = null;
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
   chrome.tabCapture.capture({
      video: true,
      audio: false,
      videoConstraints: {
        mandatory: {
          minWidth: 16,
          minHeight: 9,
          maxWidth: 1280,
          maxHeight: 720,
          maxFrameRate: 25,  // Note: Frame rate is variable (0 <= x <= 60).
        },
      },
    },
    function(stream) {
      alert(stream);
      if (!stream) {
        console.log('Error starting tab capture: ' + (chrome.runtime.lastError.message || 'UNKNOWN'));
        return;
      }
      if (receiver != null) {
        receiver.close();
      }
      receiver = window.open('receiver.html');
      receiver.currentStream = stream;
    }
  );
});
```

alert(stream); is null, therefore the code returns before it can open the new tab, and pass the stream on. Help would be much appreciated

Comment: did you solve the problem, I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Sorry, in the end, we used a different approach, and captured video from canvases